# Can't work out how to turn Parse.com javascript sdk query into loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

**edit:**
Thanks @eth3lbert
it would still require writing 24 itterations...
Here is my latest attempt...

```
var animalsMarkedAt = "animalMarkedAt"
var queryMarkedPerHour = new Parse.Query("locationDeets");
y = 0
for ( var i = 0; i < 24; i++ ) {
    queryMarkedPerHour.equalTo("dayMonthYear", dayNowMonthNowYearNowInspectorSelected) &&         queryMarkedPerHour.equalTo("hourAnimalMarked", i);
queryMarkedPerHour.count({
        success: function(j){
            y=y+1
            console.log(animalsMarkedAt + y + "oclock " + j);
        }
    })

}
```

It outputs:
animalsMarkedAt1oclock 1
animalsMarkedAt2oclock 5
animalsMarkedAt3oclock 2
etc etc (at 1am 1 animal was marked, at 2am 5 animals were marked, at 3am 2 animals were marked)
What I now need to do is assign the count to the associated name as a variable eg animalsMarkedAt1oclock should = 1
I can't work out how to assign it. It feels close.
Cheers
Dan

**Original Question:**
I am using the Parse.com Javascript SDK and need to turn the following into a loop. At the moment there are 24 of these. One for each hour.
I hope someone can help cause my code is seriously bloated.

```
var queryMarkedPerHour = new Parse.Query("locationDeets");
queryMarkedPerHour.equalTo("dayMonthYear", dayNowMonthNowYearNowInspectorSelected) && queryMarkedPerHour.equalTo("hourAnimalMarked", 7);
queryMarkedPerHour.count({
  success: function(sevenMarked){
    queryMarkedPerHour.equalTo("dayMonthYear", dayNowMonthNowYearNowInspectorSelected) && queryMarkedPerHour.equalTo("hourAnimalMarked", 8);
    queryMarkedPerHour.count({
      success: function(eightMarked){
        queryMarkedPerHour.equalTo("dayMonthYear", dayNowMonthNowYearNowInspectorSelected) && queryMarkedPerHour.equalTo("hourAnimalMarked", 9);
        queryMarkedPerHour.count({
          success: function(nineMarked){        
            //Do the Stuff
          }
        })
       }
     })
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try `Promises` to make your code cleaner.

```
var queryMarkedPerHour = new Parse.Query("locationDeets");
queryMarkedPerHour.equalTo("dayMonthYear", dayNowMonthNowYearNowInspectorSelected);
queryMarkedPerHour.equalTo("hourAnimalMarked", 7);
return queryMarkedPerHour.count()
    .then(function (sevenMarked) {
        queryMarkedPerHour.equalTo("dayMonthYear", dayNowMonthNowYearNowInspectorSelected);
        queryMarkedPerHour.equalTo("hourAnimalMarked", 8);
        return queryMarkedPerHour.count();
    })
    .then(function (eightMarked) {
        queryMarkedPerHour.equalTo("dayMonthYear", dayNowMonthNowYearNowInspectorSelected);
        queryMarkedPerHour.equalTo("hourAnimalMarked", 9);
        return queryMarkedPerHour.count();
    });// if need just keep chaining
```

ref. [Promises](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#promises)

Comment: And there are other constraints like greaterThan, lessThan, greaterThanOrEqualTo, lessThanOrEqualTo available, might be also useful to you.